# Changing User's Password In SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, change-password

I installed Microsoft SQL server 2012. I open Microsoft SQL server management and login with Windows Authentication. I don't know the default password of "sa". So, I need to change it.
I follow steps from the answer to this question: [Unable to change the password of "sa" in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11308921/unable-to-change-the-password-of-sa-in-sql-server-2008) but the password doesn't change!

For better sense see these screenshots in order:

1. I select logins. After, I select "sa". Then, select "Properties".

[image]

2. As you can see, the length of the password is 15 chars.

[image]

3. I change it to "1234". (the length of the password logically will equal to 4 chars) And then select "OK"

[image]

4. I tried login with SQL Server Authentication
   [image]
   But I cannot login to the system.
   [image]

Do you have any idea about this strange problem?

**Some Unsuccessful Tries**

- I have tried other passwords with complex char likes "@#FGHbnm1234567890"
- I changed the mode of authentication with this link [Options to Change SQL Server to Mixed Mode Authentication](https://www.top-password.com/knowledge/sql-server-authentication-mode.html)
- I have reinstalled the SQL server.
- I have created a new user. But the password of the new user isn't changeable likes "sa"

**UPDATE**

The first I said length of the password isn't correct. But I have noticed the length of the password isn't real length for the security aspect. I edit step 4 with a better reason for my claim

**UPDATE 2**

I open logs:
[image]
It seems my authentication mode is wrong:

> Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: An attempt to login using SQL
> authentication failed. The server is configured for Windows authentication
> only. [CLIENT: ]

But I change authentication mode before:

> SQL Server and windows Authentication mode

[image]

**UPDATE 3**

Finally, my problem was solved!
The reason for my problem is wrong changing authentication mode. The answer of Larnu is a good solution. Also, I suggest this link for step by step guide: [How To Enable SQL Server Authentication](https://www.dundas.com/support/learning/documentation/installation/how-to-enable-sql-server-authentication)

Comment: Why do you say the password isn't changed? If you input a new password, clicked "OK", and there wasn't an error, the password *was* changed.

Comment: The UI *always* shows 15 dots, it doesn't know what the existing password is. Why not try *using* the changed password to login instead, which should work.

Comment: Adding  the the other comments, SSMS does not show the actual password length for security reasons.

Comment: @Larnu I doesn't get error and it seems this process is successful.  But when I again see password of sa, I see old pasword length. Also, I logout from Microsoft SQL Server management and when enter new password with SQL Server Authentication I get "login failed for user sa".

Comment: *"see old pasword length"* As the others have said, SSMS doesn't tell you the length of the password; it doesn't know it. Exposing information, such as the length, of the password would be a huge security concern. The 15 • characters are simply placeholders.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever 
I don't know this fact. But I try SQL server Authentication and I cannot login

Comment: Please see UPDATE.

Comment: Those images tell us nothing. Check the SQL Server's logs instead, and find the connection failure log and post that error in your question.

Comment: Are you certain you are running mixed mode authentication (and not windows only). Please post a screenshot to confirm. When you installed SQL Server it would have asked you to enter a password for sa. If it didn't you are in windows only authentication (which is usually a good idea)

Comment: @Larnu I add UPDATE 2

Comment: ... @AlirezaMazochi read the error. *" Server is configured for Windows authentication only."* There's your problem.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Your guess is correct. But I don't know why it wasn't applied. See UPDATE 2

Comment: @Larnu Yes right for you. Do you have any solution for this?

Comment: Did you restart SQL Server after changing the authentication mode? Restart it, reset the sa password again, and try again

Comment: and congrats for taking the effort to look at the log, this will be helpful for you in future.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I restart in before. But at now I test it again and I say result. Thanks for useful helps friend

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid It seems I wasn't restart database correctly. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The real problem here is that you have your server configured in Windows authentication only. You **cannot** connect to an instance using SQL Authentication if it's in Windows Authentication only mode, because (to state the obvious) SQL Authentication is *not* Windows Authentication.

You need to [change the authentication mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/change-server-authentication-mode?view=sql-server-ver15) of the server:

> ### Enable sa login
>
> You can enable the sa login with SSMS or T-SQL.
>
> #### Use SSMS
>
> 1. In Object Explorer, expand Security, expand Logins, right-click sa, and then click Properties.
> 2. On the General page, you might have to create and confirm a password for the sa login.
> 3. On the Status page, in the Login section, click Enabled, and then click OK.
>
> #### Using Transact-SQL
>
> The following example enables the sa login and sets a new password. Replace  with a strong password before you run it.
>
> ```sql
> ALTER LOGIN sa ENABLE ;  
> GO  
> ALTER LOGIN sa WITH PASSWORD = '<enterStrongPasswordHere>' ;  
> GO
> ```
>
> ### Change authentication mode (T-SQL)
>
> The following example changes Server Authentication from mixed mode (Windows + SQL) to Windows only.
>
> > **Caution**
> >
> > The following example uses an extended stored procedure to modify the server registry. Serious problems might occur if you modify the registry incorrectly. These problems might require you to reinstall the operating system. Microsoft cannot > guarantee that these problems can be resolved. Modify the registry at your own risk.
>
> ```sql
> USE [master]
> GO
> EXEC xp_instance_regwrite N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', 
>      N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer',
>      N'LoginMode', REG_DWORD, 1
> GO
> ```

For mixed authentication, the final parameter would be `2`, not `1`.

Comment: I feel like there's something you're missing then, @AlirezaMazochi . Perhaps you don't have the permissions. I also *assume* you restarted the instance afterwards.

Comment: Right for you. I use this link for change authentication mode. Thanks a lot! :
https://www.dundas.com/support/learning/documentation/installation/how-to-enable-sql-server-authentication