# Database connection in ASP Classic

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic

I got an ASP-Classic Page from 2001.

I upgraded/migrated the Database to an actual SQL Server Version (2016).
My problem is, when I try to connect to the database I always get an error message, that I cannot connect to the server because of the given user. I created a user on my SQL Server, this is the one I want to use for the connection but it doesn't work.

Here's the code:

```
Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=LV; User ID=lvsupervisor;Password=analogis;
```

The login credentials are correct. Maybe someone can help me here.

Comment: Check the SQL Server's logs, what does the error say there? Then post that here if you don't understand it.

Comment: It says that theserver is only configured for windows authentification, how can i change that?

Comment: Posted an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64571005/2029983) that demonstrate that not but a few hours ago. :)

Comment: Ah thanks, I'll try that.

Comment: This worked, thank you! But Now i get an error that my user has no db_datareader rights, even though i checked the checkbox under "User Mapping" in the Sql Server settings

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing User's Password In SQL Server 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64570185/changing-users-password-in-sql-server-2012)

Answer (score 0):

`ASP Classic 3` itself works smoothly even with latest version of `MS SQL` (2019).

> My problem is, when I try to connect to the database I always get an error message, that I cannot connect to the server because of the given user.

First of all verify that user itself able to login to MS SQL Server. Run MS SQL Management Studio and try to login to server by using user credential you have. Does it works? Could you see data in Tables?

> migrated the Database to an actual SQL Server Version (2016)

Connection string: try different provider, for example `Provider=SQLOLEDB.1`

Answer (score 0):

Delete your current DSN and create a new one using "SQL Server Authentication" instead of "Windows Authentication". Create a new user with admin/read/write permissions and nominate that account for the new DSN connection. Use a 64-bit DSN for default server or if you have enabled 32-bit applications for the site, then you must use a 32-bit DSN connection. Then you can use...

```
strConnection = "DSN=ExampleName;DRIVER={SQL Server};UID=ExampleUser;PWD=ExamplePass"

Set dbConnection = server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
dbConnection.ConnectionString = strConnection
dbConnection.Open

SQLFunction = "SELECT ID FROM Example Where CExample.Key = '" & strInputCom & "' "
    Set rsFunction = dbConnection.Execute(SQLFunction)
        if not rsFunction.EOF then
        strClientId = rsFunction("ID").value    
    else
        strClientId = ""
    end if              
    rsFunction.Close
    Set rsFunction = Nothing
```